# Dynamically set active tab with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm trying to set a tab active dynamically. I have search the net but the solutions is not working.Here is my code.

```
<ul id="memnav" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="tab" href="#publication-tab">
        Publications
    </a>
    </li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#project-tab">Projects</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
        About me
        <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#education-tab">Education</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#career-tab">Career</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#contact-tab">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and in the script

```
var active_tab = sessionStorage.getItem('active_tab');
        if(active_tab){
            $("#memnav").tabs().tabs( "option", "active", active_tab);
        }
```

But it throws this error

> Uncaught Error: jQuery UI Tabs: Mismatching fragment identifier.

I have also put the "ul" inside a "div" but it shows the same error

Comment: shouldn't the duplicate .tabs() be removed?

Comment: If i remove that first one it give me another error.

Comment: how about: `$('#memnav a').on('click', function(){$('#memnav .active').removeClass('active');$(this).closest('li').addClass('active');});` ?

Comment: do you want on click or when page loaded??

Comment: no i don't want to click. Actually the target is on other tabs there are some update button so after updating the returned page should be active on the tab from which the previous event occurred.

Comment: and where the num of tab save in param??

Comment: Oh that real code is not here i was just testing if i could set the tab active in this way. The real tab index is stored in the sessionStorage. From there i will get which tab should bet set to active.

Comment: this is the real code var active_tab = sessionStorage.getItem('active_tab');
            if(active_tab){
                $("#memnav").tabs().tabs( "option", "active", active_tab);
            }

Comment: see my edit please

Comment: i already edited

Comment: i mean see my edit answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply use `addClass` 
add `.eq()` :https://api.jquery.com/eq/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var i=0;//get from storrage
$("#memnav li").eq(i).addClass('active');
});
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul id="memnav" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li>
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="tab" href="#publication-tab">
        Publications
    </a>
    </li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#project-tab">Projects</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
        About me
        <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#education-tab">Education</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#career-tab">Career</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#contact-tab">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Comment: I don't want to make the first li element active it could be anyone. it have to be dynamic

Comment: does it help you??

Comment: ya it kind of helped but not fully. The tab li element is showing active but the correspondent div is not showing

Comment: Thanks though it's not fully worked for me but it shows me the path how to solve. Thanks

Comment: Hi Fuad, I assume you are looking to set the href value in the session and then make the list-item active where that href value matches ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as well :)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var active_tab = '#publication-tab';
 $('#memnav').find('a[href="'+active_tab+'"]').parent().addClass('active');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul id="memnav" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li>
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="tab" href="#publication-tab">
        Publications
    </a>
    </li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#project-tab">Projects</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
        About me
        <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#education-tab">Education</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#career-tab">Career</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#contact-tab">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```